# Is there an offline HTML editor for writers?

Tags: html, microsoft-word

All of our writers and editors use Microsoft Word for document creation and a lot of what they create ends up on the Web. Is there a good offline editor with a flavor similar to Word that they could use to create their documents. Styling of the content should not be a concern, only producing semantic HTML (most documents they create could be done using only header and paragraph tags for instance). They have tried CKEditor and TinyMCE but it is still too foreign for them and it is online so they don't trust it not to lose their work.

Comment: When you googled HTML editor, what did you find?  Where there dozens?  Do you have specific questions about any of the dozens of off-line editors?

Comment: Notepad++ perhaps

Comment: Shouldn't this question be posted on http://superuser.com ?

Comment: @incarnate That's what I voted for. :-/

Comment: This was closed as "off-topic". Shouldn't it have been migrated to superuser.com instead?

Comment: @mipadi Yep. I've voted to reopen so we can send it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ is a good editor for almost anything. http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Forgot to mention, its FREE. So no pain to try it out.

Comment: We're talking about people currently using, of all things, *Word* as an HTML editor. I have a feeling WYSIWYG is required, and last I checked, you won't get that in Notepad++.

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org) and its XHTML export? From what little I've toyed around with it, it produces very clean code - turns OpenOffice headings into HTML headings and so on. It even exports images as inline "data" URLs.

Answer (score 1):

Live Writer, Adobe Dreamweaver, Visual Studio.